# NodeJS get IPs from hostname

Tags: node.js

My /etc/hosts file has entries:

```
IP1 host1
IP2 host2
IP3 host3
IP4 host3
IP5 host3
```

Now I need IPs for host3 (IP3, IP4, IP5). One way is to read this file and then parse out this information. Is there a better way of getting this list?

Answer (score 0):

No, I would say there is no better way to get the whole list than parsing the file.

However, if you are fine with just getting one IP address, use the underlying operating system facilities to resolve names. `dns.lookup` will ask your OS, and your OS will check /etc/hosts for you...

```
var dns = require('dns');

dns.lookup('host3', function onLookup(err, addr, family) {
  console.log('addresses:', addr);
});
```

Comment: This shall provide only the 1st address, and not the list. https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback

Comment: Aha, yes, that's right. I missunderstood your question.

Comment: Changed my answer. *nix OSes in general has no way to return the whole list for you. I would say there is no better way than parsing the file.